# Can't list bucket objects on Scaleway using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I saw a few similar posts, but unfortunately none helped me.
I have an s3 bucket (on scaleway), and I'm trying to simply list all objects contained in that bucket, using boto3 s3 client as follow:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  region_name=AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
                  endpoint_url=AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
                  aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  )

all_objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

This simple piece of code responds with an error:

`botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified key does not exist.`

First, the error seems inapropriate to me since I'm not specifying any key to search. I also tried to pass a `Prefix` argument to this method to narrow down the search to a specific subdirectory, same error.
Second, I tried to achieve the same thing using boto3 `Resource` rather than `Client`, as follow:

```
session = boto3.Session(
    region_name=AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)
resource = session.resource(
    's3',
    endpoint_url=AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
)

for bucket in resource.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

That code produces absolutely nothing. One weird thing that strikes me is that I don't pass the `bucket_name` anywhere here, which seems to be normal according to [aws documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session)

There's no chance that I misconfigured the client, since I'm able to use the `put_object` method perfectly with that same client. One strange though: when I want to put a file, I pass the whole path to `put_object` as `Key` (as I found it to be the way to go), but the object is inserted with the bucket name prepend to it. So let's say I call `put_object(Key='/path/to/myfile.ext')`, the object will end up to be `/bucket-name/path/to/myfile.ext`.

Is this strange behavior the key to my problem ? How can I investigate what's happening, or is there another way I could try to list bucket files ?

Thank you

EDIT: So, after logging the request that `boto3` client is sending, I noticed that the bucket name is append to the url, so instead of requesting `https://<bucket_name>.s3.<region>.<provider>/`, it requests `https://<bucket_name>.s3.<region>.<provider>/<bucket-name>/`, which is leading to the `NoSuchKey` error.
I took a look into the `botocore` library, and I found this:

```
url = _urljoin(endpoint_url, r['url_path'], host_prefix)
```

in `botocore.awsrequest` line 252, where `r['url_path']` contains `/skichic-bucket?list-type=2`. So from here, I should be able to easily patch the library core to make it work for me.

Plus, the `Prefix` argument is not working, whatever I pass into it I always receive the whole bucket content, but I guess I can easily patch this too.

Now it's not satisfying, since there's no issue related to this on github, I can't believe that the library contains such a bug that I'm the first one to encounter.

Does anyone can explain this whole mess ? >.<

Comment: The last snippet of code doesn't try to list bucket objects, it's listing all S3 buckets in your account for the given region.

Comment: @jordanm yep you're right, still, it does not return anything

Comment: What does AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL contain? It's not common to override the defaults for that.

Comment: @jordanm The OP is using [S3-compatible Object Storage - Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com/en/object-storage/), hence the need to specify an Endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more closely into things, I've found out that (a lot) of `botocore` services endpoints patterns starts with the bucket name. For example, here's the definition of the `list_objects_v2` service:

```
"ListObjectsV2":{
      "name":"ListObjectsV2",
      "http":{
        "method":"GET",
        "requestUri":"/{Bucket}?list-type=2"
      },
```

My guess is that in the standard implementation of AWS S3, there's a generic`endpoint_url` (which explains [@jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) comment) and the targeted bucket is reached through the endpoint.

Now, in the case of Scaleway, there's an `endpoint_url` for each bucket, with the bucket name contained in that url (e.g `https://<bucket_name>.s3.<region>.<provider>`), and any endpoint should directly starts with a bucket `Key`.

I made a [fork](https://github.com/elachere/scw_botocore) of `botocore` where I rewrote every endpoint to remove the bucket name, if that can help someone in the future.

Thank's again to all contributors !

Answer (score 6):

For those who are facing the same issue, try changing your `endpoint_url` parameter in your boto3 client or resource instantiation from `https://<bucket_name>.s3.<region>.<provider>` to `https://s3.<region>.<provider>` ; *i.e* for Scaleway : `https://s3.<region>.scw.cloud`.

You can then set the `Bucket` parameter to select the bucket you want.

```
list_objects_v2(Bucket=<bucket_name>)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. you'll have to use your resource instead of my s3sr.

```
s3sr = resource('s3')
bucket = 'your-bucket'
prefix = 'your-prefix/' # if no prefix, pass ''

def get_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    '''gets list of keys for given bucket and prefix'''
    keys_list = []
    paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    # use Delimiter to limit search to that level of hierarchy
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
        print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
        keys_list.extend(keys)
    return keys_list

keys_list = get_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix)
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer! Unfortunately it raises the same error `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey`. I think I'm gonna ask scaleway support, maybe there's something wrong with their s3 integration ?

Comment: I looked at the scaleway link, boto3 doesn't look to be supported. Aws command line is mentioned as well as others methods. Good luck.

Comment: In this [example](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/object-storage-post-object/) they use boto3 so I figured it should work

Comment: Point taken. Wondering if you used the example as is to see if you could create a pre signed url. And use requests to get the object. Also you have a slightly different implementation of the session and client. Maybe try using exact syntax they use.

Comment: [@Jonathan Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12133434/jonathan-leon) It's definitly something weird with scaleway implementation. I'll explain what I've found in my answer, and also put a link to a fork from botocore that I made.